# Touch not detected on MKAnnotationView on zoom-in

Tags: xcode, touch, zooming, mkannotationview

I have added a tapGestureRegognizer on a MKAnnotationView.
I added a pin annotation on the map.

There is a certain area around the pin, which is un-clickable. When I zoom-in on the map, this area becomes larger. In this buffer area/padding area, touch does not work at all.

Is this the correct behavior?
Please help...

Comment: Why do you need a tap gesture recognizer instead of just using the didSelectAnnotationView delegate method?  Show how you are creating the annotation view and adding the recognizer.